# Nginx rewrite send all query params except one

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to remove a certain query param from the request URI, before redirecting the user from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`. The query param is `migrate`.

So from this URL:
`domain1.com/check?migrate=true&uuid=1821`

I want to take the user to this URL:
`domain2.com/check?uuid=1821`

There can be a lot more query params, and I want to keep them all except `migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply a regular expression to a variable that contains the entire query string - so either `$request_uri` or `$args` are possible candidates.

To redirect just `/check`, you could use:

```
location = /check {
    if ($args ~* ^(.*&)?migrate=[^&]*(&(.*))?$)
        return 301 http://domain2.com$uri?$1$3;
    }
    return 301 http://domain2.com$uri?$args;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.